# .NET Framework API on Azure receives body bytes with all zeros sometimes

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have a .NET Framework API hosted on Azure.
I have a POST endpoint on this API receiving some data through the body (json content, utf-8 encoding).
Most of the requests are successful, however, sometimes I get a `NullReferenceException` because my model is `null`.

I'm logging the request information on that endpoint and I get that:

- Request content length is the same for successful and unsuccessful requests;
- When the body is `null`, the content bytes are all zeroes. So it's not that the body is missing: it's there, but somehow all the positions of the request's byte array are converted to zeroes.

Also, by using Fiddler on my end I know that I'm sending the body correctly at all times.

This is really weird.

Any ideas?

Edit: I can't reproduce this behavior running localhost or with local IIS, only at Azure.

Edit: We have an extension method to read the request information:

```
public static string GetBody(this HttpRequest request)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        request.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
        request.InputStream.Position = 0;

        stream.Position = 0;
        var bytes = stream.ToArray();
        stream.Position = 0;

        return $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Replace("  ", "")} | RequestLength: {request.InputStream.Length} | ArrayLength: {bytes.Length} | Array: {string.Join(" ", bytes)}";
    }
}
```

Comment: "When the body is null, the content bytes are all zeroes" - how are you seeing that?

Comment: @Dai I edited the question with the code snippet that generates the log line. This is also on the first middleware of my API, which indicates the body already arrives messed up.

Comment: You are removing newlines, and squeezing spaces, but still returning the original length values of InputStream and bytes array - is that not confusing whoever reads this returned body string?

Comment: `request.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);` this line can throw exceptions, have you handled that ?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran thanks for the feedback, I'm not particularly worried about the log message format, and that line is not throwing exceptions for us (tho surely we should wrap it in a try/catch block). So far it's allowing us to interpret the current problem with our server. Do you have any ideas regarding the issue itself? As an update, we've identified Azure's WAF can be the culprit, even tho we don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[request.InputStream.CanRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.canread?view=net-6.0)** and **[request.InputStream.CanSeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.canseek?view=net-6.0)** so you can safely **re-position** the cursor in the stream and later can read it.

Reading directly from the Request. When re-reading, **InputStream** will return null, even if the data is present.

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/706456/why-is-contextrequestinputstream-empty.html) for more information

Comment: Hey @Mari Faleiros! had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?